# Eyeshot component RenderToBitmap resolution

Tags: c#, eyeshot

I am trying to generate a picture of my 3D model using the ViewPortLayout

```
ViewportLayoutBinding viewportLayout;
....
viewportLayout.RenderToBitmap(1,false)
```

but the picture i obtain has a low resolution (the same resolution as what is shown on the Screen) and most of the text (quotes) can't be read.
I have tried to change the resolution in the render Method, to modify the camera parameters, but it won't change anything.

Is there a way to set a better resolution for the picture i want to generate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter is image scaling. Please try specifying 2 or 5 instead.

Comment: it Worked, i did tried to change it before but with only 2, i did not see much of a difference. With a higher value it definility solves my  issue. Thank you